# Is email forwarding to the sender's address usually blocked in Mail servers / MTA?

Tags: email, forwarding

I've noticed that email forwarding to an address seems not to work if I send an email from the address to which I am forwarding email. This happens for GMail and Fasthosts mail servers. e.g I send an email to `info@mail.com` from `myaddress@mail.com` , `info@mail.com` is set to forward to `myaddress@mail.com` and the email never arrives.

I realise this seems logical but it is a potential cause of confusion when testing email functionality in a web application (for me, anyway ;-). I would just like to know if this is standard for all MTA software so I can avoid confusing myself.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is in no way "standard" to block mail in this manner.  I suspect whatever problem you are experiencing was caused by something else entirely, but it's difficult to say what without a lot more information.